# Remove or filter duplicate holidays events from calendar database - Android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I am fetching all calendar events including **holidays** from Android Calendar Database using Content providers. **As I am signed in with two different Gmail accounts**, the Query returns duplicate **holidays**. I want to avoid duplicate Holidays and I am trying to do the same by making changes in Query.

Is it possible to avoid duplicate holidays by making changes in the query? Can someone help me with making a proper query which by default avoids duplicate Holidays? Or is there any other solution for this issue?

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] PROJECTION = { CalendarContract.Events._ID,
            CalendarContract.Events.TITLE ,
            CalendarContract.Events.OWNER_ACCOUNT,
            CalendarContract.Events.ACCOUNT_NAME,
            CalendarContract.Events.ACCOUNT_TYPE};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null,
            null);


    int titleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE);
    int eventIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Events._ID);
    int ownerAccountIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Events.OWNER_ACCOUNT);
    int accountNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Events.ACCOUNT_NAME);
    int accountTypeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Events.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

    String[] result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(titleIndex);
        String id = cursor.getString(eventIdIndex);
        String ownerAccount = cursor.getString(ownerAccountIndex);
        String accountName = cursor.getString(accountNameIndex);
        String accountType = cursor.getString(accountTypeIndex);
        result[cursor.getPosition()] = name + "(" + id + ")"+" ownerAccount->"+ownerAccount+", accountName-->"+accountName+" accountType->"+accountType;

        Log.d("AllDataLog","* result->"+result[cursor.getPosition()]);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
}
```

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/how-to-avoid-duplicate-generated-calendar-entries

Comment: Hi, @MartinZeitler Thanks for the reply. But I am looking to solve this issue programmatically. I am working on one Android app, which needs a calendar data. The link which you have shared is not the solution to my question

Comment: Change `null, null, null`... or just check for column `IS_PRIMARY`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler one of the `null` stands for **Where clause**. Could you please elaborate more? What condition should I add to where clause. I tried using `DISTINCT` in projection. But that didn't work

Comment: I have already posted about this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959485/2661303 You can probably do it in the query using GROUP_BY Title, Time, IS_PRIMARY, etc. But I would rather suggest doing it in code by looping through results and avoiding duplicates, as it gives you more finite control.

Comment: @lionscribe, Thanks. I will try to implement it in this way.